# Des italiques entre guillemets dans les commentaires — Quoted italics inside comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, comments

J’ai pu remarquer que taper [`“*un truc*”` dans un commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7337/is-the-word-order-in-this-sentence-correct#comment12151_7339) n’aboutissait pas au-même “*un truc*” que dans les questions et réponses elles-même. Le texte ne passe pas en italique et les astérisques demeurent visibles ; or il me semble plus logique de taper `“* *”` que `*“ “*`. Après tout, les guillemets sont anglaises, il n’y a aucune raison de les passer en italique.

Je suppose que c’est un problème généralisé à tout SE, mais qui apparaît rarement sur les autres sites. Est-ce quelque chose qui a déjà été discuté ?

---

I’ve noticed that typing `“*something*”` inside comments didn’t result in “*something*” as it does inside a question or answer. The text remains upright and the asteriks remains visible. However, I think it’s more logical to type `“* *”` rather than `*“ ”*`. These are english quotes, they shouldn’t be in italics.

I guess this is an SE-wide issue which occurs rarely on other SE sites. Was it discussed somewhere?

Comment: Et je le prouve : “*un truc*”.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that the comment parser doesn't treat “*U+201C and U+201D*” as word separators and so doesn't interpret the `*…*` as italics delimiters. "*U+0022 works*". It works fine in the full markdown parser used in posts.

Comment: This has been [reported on the main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96669/problem-with-markdown-and-unicode-characters-in-comments) and marked [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. I'm going to leave this one to the developers because I think the decision should be reconsidered.

Comment: @Gilles: I realize that I posted a duplicate of this post more recently http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164146/inconsistent-parsing-of-markdown-wrt-italics-and-punctuation-in-posts-and-commen. More upvotes and no status-by-design yet. But I guess it should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Oded Why? It would seem like this bug would be easy to fix, and on language sites it affects us very often.

Comment: @Gilles - we are reviewing this in the dev team. I was using the bydesign by Jeff as a guide, but decided to ask the team, seeing as the decision was made long before we had language sites. Not sure we will support the [whole set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks) though...

Answer (score 4):

These and a few other quote characters will work as expected from the next site build on; see [my answer on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197962/115866).